# Testing SOLR to Elasticsearch data transfer

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I have recently moved my entire SOLR documents into Elasticsearch after creating an exact equivalent mapping of the schema.xml . To test the accuracy, i created about 120 lucene queries and queried it on SOLR and elasticsearch.

However on testing the hitcounts for 17/120 queries differed between SOLR and elasticsearch.Could there be any reasons for this apart from the analyzers, tokenizers, filters defined in schema.xml/ elasticsearch mappings. The SOLR version is 4.3.0 whereas the elasticsearch version is 1.3.2

The elasticsearch query i used is :

```
{"query_string":{"query":lucene_query}}
```

Please let me know, if there is any alternative way to test the query accuracy between SOLR and Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you are using the same semantics. For example, same filters, tokenizers, stemmers.

Also, Apache Solr 4.3.0 is built on Apache Lucene 4.3.0 , while ElasticSearch 1.3.2 is built on Apache Lucene 4.9.0
This might not be the issue, I don't know to be honest. But if I were you, I would check the release notes of Apache Lucene > 4.3.0 and see what is changed.

Comment: The filters, tokenizers and stemmers are the exact same. I'll also check up the release notes. Thanks for the suggestion.